# How to execute my HelloWorld script

Tags: java, cmd

I'm currently trying to run my first `java` script:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I decided i'd take a little look into Java. However I come from languages like JavaScript and PHP which don't require any compiling or anything as such.

So far, I think i'm compiling it correctly in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Shawn>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javac.exe" "HelloWorld.java"
```

It adds a file called: `HelloWorld.class` so figured I did something right.

However, now when I try to actually run the program using:

```
C:\Users\Shawn>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe" "C:\Users\Shawn\HelloWorld.class"
```

I get this, `Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\Shawn\HelloWorld.class`.

However, if I try that same command but use `javac.exe` instead I get:

```
javac: invalid flag: C:\Users\Shawn\HelloWorld.class
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Why is this happening? Why isn't my program executing correctly?

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe" HelloWorld`

Answer (score 9):

The `java` command takes the name of the *class*, not the name of the file.
It then uses the Java class loader to find the `.class` file for that class in the current directory or the class path.

When you pass `HelloWorld.class`, it looks for a class named `class` in the package `HelloWorld.`
(that would be `./HelloWorld/class.class`)

You need to pass `HelloWorld`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the argument needs to be just the class name, without the extension `.class`. There is a second requirement that must be met, though: the class file must be in the [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

It's usually not advisable (although convenient) to include the current directory in the global classpath, but you can override it on the command line:

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

You can also specify an explicit path:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\Shawn" HelloWorld
```

If your Java program uses other classes, include the global classpath like this:

```
java -cp "%CLASSPATH%;." HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following javac [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) for more info. especially the section on Cross-Compilation Options.